# Android Beta app declared as "Unreleased"

Tags: android, release, beta, developer-console

I created a beta test for my android app. The problem is that if you click on the store it says (unreleased) and not (beta). What does unreleased mean? Im confused because its a public beta that you should find in the appstore. I only tested downloading it with my developer account.

Configuration:
[image: Configuration]

In Appstore:
[image: Appstore]

Comment: could you check it for me pls? "Blueberry fitness tracker". Consider we have a new icon. So just watch out for the title.

Comment: Here "unreleased" means "not a final product" in a sense of a product life-cycle. So, it can be argued that "unreleased" covers all stages prior to stable release: alpha, beta, theta, etc.

Comment: FWIW, your app is showing up on search results.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will start productionstate tomorrow. You can write an answer than i will give you the bounty!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is that if you click on the store it says (unreleased) and not (beta).

Apparently, [Google makes distinction](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180) between beta versions based on if an app has ever been released to the public before or not. That's, if the app has never been released before and is published through alpha/beta channel first, it will be labeled "unreleased". To quote from above help page (emphasis is mine):

> Try ***unreleased*** apps through early access
>
> Early access apps are apps which have ***not been released yet***.
>
> ...
>
> Note: If you install an ***unreleased app***, you may be automatically enrolled in the beta program when that app launches.
>
> Get ***beta*** versions of apps
>
> Beta apps are new, experimental versions of apps that are ***currently available*** on the Play Store.
>
> ...

Hope this helps.